# How to calculate 2.5% pvalues for the 2 ends of the distribution?

Tags: statistical-significance, python, t-test, scipy

I am trying to compute what the 2.5% probability values are for the two ends of the distribution? here is what I am doing so far.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ttest_rel
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Opensourcefordatascience/Data-sets/master/blood_pressure.csv")

stats.ttest_rel(df['bp_before'], df['bp_after'])
Ttest_relResult(statistic=3.3371870510833657, pvalue=0.0011297914644840823)
```

I hope I was clear enough to explain since I am new to this concept. Can I get some guidance?

Comment: Could you describe in plain English what you are trying to achieve? What do you need those values for? Which distribution? How does this relate to $t$-test?

Comment: Per your title. Note that [p-values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) apply to hypothesis tests conducted on data, one is given in the output. Are you talking instead about quantiles (the 2.5% and 97.5% values of some distribution), which might for example be used as critical values in a test? If so, why would you need it, since you have a p-value already?